# How can I report progress from a PLINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

I would like to report progress from a long running PLINQ query.

I can't really find any native LINQ method that allows me to do this (as was [implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-plinq-query) for [cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withcancellation?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

I have read [this article](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/07/reporting-progress-during-linq-queries.html) that shows a neat extension function for a regular serialized query.

I have been testing the behavior using the below code.

```c#
var progress = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
progress.Subscribe(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); });
Enumerable.Range(1,1000000)
    //.WithProgressReporting(i => progress.OnNext(i)) //Beginning Progress
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    //.WithProgressReporting(i => progress.OnNext(i)) //Middle Progress reporting
    .Select(v => { Thread.Sleep(1); return v * v; })
    //.WithProgressReporting(i => progress.OnNext(i)) //End Progress Reporting
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Completed in: " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds + " seconds");
```

Edit:
Reporting progress from the **middle** using the `IEnumerable<T>` extension removes the parallelism.

Reporting from the **end** does not report any progress while the parallel calculations are being computed then quickly reports all the progress at the very end. I assume this is progress of compiling of the results from the parallel computation into a list.

I originally thought the progress reporting from **beginning** was causing the the LINQ to run unparallelized. After sleeping on this, and reading comments from [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584078/how-can-i-report-progress-from-a-plinq-query#comment97866126_55584078), I see that it is actually working as parallel, but I am getting so many progress reports that handling so many is causing my test/application to slow significantly.

Is there a way that is parallel/thread safe to report progress from a PLINQ in increments that allow a user to know progress is being made without having a significant impact on the method runtime?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why doesn't the non-parallel `WithProgressReporting()` method serve your purpose adequately? Typically, you'd be starting with `IEnumerable<T>` anyway...just wrap your source `IEnumerable<T>` with the call to `WithProgressReporting()` and call `AsParallel()` on that, as you've done in your tests. Ultimately the throughput is going to be same, whether you report progress on the source or result. You need to be more specific: post a [mcve] and explain _precisely_ what output it is you expect, and what you're getting instead.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not be as elegant, but it gets the job done.

When using PLINQ, there are multiple threads processing your collection, so using those threads to **report** progress results in multiple (and out-of-order) progress reports like 0% 1% 5% 4% 3% etc...

Instead, we can use those multiple threads to **update** a shared variable storing the progress. In my example, it's a local variable `completed`. We then spawn another thread using `Task.Run()` to report on that progress variable at 0.5s intervals.

Extension class:

```
static class Extensions
    public static ParallelQuery<T> WithProgressReporting<T>(this ParallelQuery<T> sequence, Action increment)
    {
        return sequence.Select(x =>
        {
            increment?.Invoke();
            return x;
        });
    }
}
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long completed = 0;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (completed < 100000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((completed * 100 / 100000) + "%");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        var output = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000)
            .AsParallel()
            .WithProgressReporting(()=>Interlocked.Increment(ref completed))
            .Select(v => { Thread.Sleep(1); return v * v; })
            .ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed in: " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds + " seconds");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [linked article](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/07/reporting-progress-during-linq-queries.html) by Samuel Jack provides two overloads of the `WithProgressReporting` operator, one with `itemCount` parameter (second) and one without (first). According to the author's instructions, you have to use the overload that has the `itemCount` parameter:

> The second variant can be used if generating the items in the sequence takes time (so you want to report progress of this part as well), but you know in advance how many there will be: it doesn't attempt to buffer the sequence before passing the items through to the output sequence.

You also have to use the PLINQ operator [`WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withmergeoptions), otherwise the elements produced by the PLINQ query will not be propagated immediately downstream, causing undesirable delays in the progress reporting.

Samuel Jack's implementation reports progress for each and every element produced by the source sequence, which is too much. Below is a more sophisticated implementation, that reports progress at most 101 times, from 0 to 100:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reports progress 0-100.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WithProgressReporting<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, long itemsCount,
    IProgress<int> progress)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(progress);
    if (itemsCount < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(itemsCount));

    progress.Report(0);
    long i = 0;
    long next = GetNext(0, itemsCount, out _);
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == next)
        {
            next = GetNext(i, itemsCount, out int percentDone);
            progress.Report(percentDone);
        }
        yield return item;
    }
    if (i == 0 || itemsCount == 0) progress.Report(100);

    static long GetNext(long itemsDone, long itemsCount, out int percentDone)
    {
        if (itemsCount == 0) { percentDone = 0; return long.MaxValue; }
        checked
        {
            // Calculate the percent of the work done, rounding down
            percentDone = (int)(itemsDone * 100 / itemsCount);
            // Calculate the next iteration to report, rounding up
            long next = (((percentDone + 1) * itemsCount - 1) / 100) + 1;
            Debug.Assert(next > itemsDone);
            return next;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(e => Console.WriteLine(e));
long sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 1_000_000)
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
    .Select(n =>
    {
        Thread.SpinWait(100); // Simulate some lightweight computation
        return (long)n;
    })
    .AsSequential() // End of parallelism
    .WithProgressReporting(1_000_000, progress) // <--- the extension method
    .Sum();
```

I've included the [`AsSequential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.assequential) operator, although it's not needed, to signify visually the completion of the parallel part of the query. Both the `WithProgressReporting` and the [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum) are standard sequential LINQ operators, not parallel.

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gscWFe).

The `GetNext` local function does some precise integer divisions, in order to calculate the next iteration that needs to trigger a progress report. I have tested and validated the correctness of the calculations, for all possible `itemsCount` values in the range 0 - 10,000.

The built-in [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class invokes asynchronously the `handler` on the captured synchronization context. In case there is no synchronization context, for example in a console application, the `handler` is invoked on the `ThreadPool`. This might be undesirable, because it means that the `handler` might be invoked after the completion of the PLINQ query. You can solve this problem by using a synchronous [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) implementation, like the `SynchronousProgress<T>` that I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777719/using-taskcompletionsource-within-an-await-task-run-call/59786280#59786280). Alternatively you could replace the `IProgress<int> progress` parameter with an `Action<int> reportProgress`, as is in [Samuel Jack's](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/07/reporting-progress-during-linq-queries.html) article.